# Apache stops working after installing Homebrew PHP (which is missing on Monterey)

Tags: macos, homebrew, apache, php, monterey

Hello I have followed [these instructions to configure](https://tech-cookbook.com/2020/11/14/setting-up-your-local-web-server-on-macos-big-sur-11-0-1-2020-mamp-macos-apache-mysql-php/) builtin Apache web server on Macos 12.1, although I have realised that PHP was removed by Apple on Monterey.
As such, I have installed homebrew and installed PHP from there, however, now Apache won't work, since the instructions below are not commented in `httpd.conf`:

```
LoadModule php_module /opt/homebrew/opt/php/lib/httpd/modules/libphp.so

    <FilesMatch \.php$>
        SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
    </FilesMatch>
```

Attempting to open localhost through Chrome, will throw:

```
This site can’t be reached127.0.0.1 refused to connect.
Try:

Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

Comment: Is httpd running at all? Is there any relevant infomraiton in the error log?

Comment: Wow! The log is empty and the httpd daemon is not running when the above is uncommented

Comment: Did you check path and access permissions (along the whole path) for the .so file?

Comment: The path was wrong. Corrected and set chmod 777 for the .so file. Anything else required?

Comment: Got this article, now seems to be working

Comment: No, not working!

Comment: I'll guarantee you that you don't want to set the library to 777, that's a remarkably bad idea.  Do you WANT anyone who cares to, to be able to root your server?

Comment: What settings should I set on the .so ?

Comment: restart from scratch here https://getgrav.org/blog/macos-monterey-apache-multiple-php-versions now working!